# how to integrate iyzico payment with flutter

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway, payment

How to integrate iyzico payment gateway to the flutter. Please help me to use and integrate iyzico payment method with flutter!!!!!

I have tried a lot of packages but didn't work for me. is there a better payment gateway in turkey to use, and integrate easily

Comment: what have you tried? and have you checked which integration methods they have? api, form, etc?

Comment: Please provide more details about what exactly you have. What error do you receive?

Answer (score 1):

You can use iyzico plugin to integrate
All methods and documentation is provided in this link
please check

[iyzico plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/iyzico)